# Merging function for merge sort

Tags: c++, sorting, merge

I am having a difficult time with the merging portion for merge sort. Every time I merge the two halves of the vector, it ends up losing at least one of the values in the vector.

```
void merge(vector <double> &v, vector <double> &temp, int start, int size) {
int i, j, k;


i = start;
j = start + size - size/2;
k = start;

temp.resize(v.size());
while(i < start+size/2 && j < start+size) {
    if(v[i] <= v[j]) {
        temp[k] = v[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    //  cout << "i <= j " << temp[k] << endl;
    } else {
        temp[k] = v[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    //  cout << "i > j "<< temp[k] << endl;
    }
}

for(i = start; i < start+size; i++) {
    v[i] = temp[i];
}
```

}

Comment: Your loop can finish by any of two conditions. You must copy  left elements from one of the arrays if any till the second condition becomes false. Currently if one part consists of 21 elements and another of 22 elements, you merge 42 elements only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't know the caller implementation and I may be wrong, but I think there are two bugs.

- First, `i` is terminated at `start+size/2` in the first while-loop.
  This value must be equal to the first value of `j` which is `start+size-size/2`.
  But, for instance, if `size==5`, then `start+5/2=start+2` and `start+5-5/2=start+3`.
  In this case `v[start+2]` is never entered to the final result.
- Secondly, after breaking out of the first while-loop, remaining values of `v` also must be assigned to `temp`.

In summary, my quick answer is as follows. Demo is [**here**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/i0L3VaEoJ2hrvfCH).

```
void merge(std::vector<double> &v, std::vector<double> &temp, int start, int size) 
{
    int i = start;             // left  array begin
    int j = i + size - size/2; // right array begin (which should be guaranteed by caller.)

    int i_max = j;             // left  array end
    int j_max = start+size;    // right array end

    int k = i;
    temp.resize(v.size());

    while(i < i_max && j < j_max) 
    {
        if(v[i] <= v[j]){
            temp[k] = v[i];
            i++;
            k++;
            //std::cout << "i <= j: " << temp[k-1] << std::endl;
        } 
        else {
            temp[k] = v[j];
            j++;
            k++;
            //std::cout << "i >  j: "<< temp[k-1] << std::endl;
        }
    }

    while (i < i_max) { 
        temp[k] = v[i]; 
        i++; 
        k++; 
    } 

    while (j < j_max) { 
        temp[k] = v[j]; 
        j++; 
        k++; 
    } 

    for(i = start; i < j_max; i++) {
        v[i] = temp[i];
    }
}
```